# Можно ли записывать все входящие-исходящие сообщения вконтакте в лог?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, вконтакте

У меня есть доступ к странице девушки, она об этом знает и поэтому постоянно удаляет сообщения, вводя меня в заблуждение. Мол пароль-то я её знаю...
Могу ли я с помощью пхп скрипта или джаббер клиента запротоколировать все сообщения и как? Хоть направте.

Comment: @victor_crimea, просмотрите, пожалуйста, данные Вам ответы и примите исчерпывающие (пока у Вас 0% принятых). Это ускорит получение ответа на данный вопрос.

Comment: «Хоть направте» – поговорите с друзьями, что ли, за жизнь. Следить за девушкой, это какая-то неправильная ситуация уже.

Comment: vk fox додаток в firefox работает

Comment: фигней страдаете. если не доверяете - меняйте девушку, если не доверяет - меняйте девушку. Просто никогда не пытайтесь лишить кого-либо личной жизни.

Comment: Выбирайте - или девушка или программирование :) А то вместе ничего не выйдет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для десктоп/мобильных клиентов есть [методы работы с личными сообщениями](http://vk.com/developers.php?s=0&id=-1_11226273). Чтобы ловить быстро стираемые сообщения, нужно относительно регулярно проверять скриптом состояние диалогов.

В случае с php надо будет создать в VK приложение типа Desktop/Mobile, запросить для него нужные права у пользователя и сохранить token, который даст в последствии возможноть php скрипту с сервера использовать вышеуказанные методы. Косяк может быть с тем, что сервер находится в другом месте, нежели обычно выходит онлайн пользователь, и ВК станет спрашивать последние 4 цифры телефона у вашего php скрипта. Есть и куча других сложностей и подводных камней. Проще найти другую девушку )

Answer (score 3):

Jabber не дает возможности считывать ее сообщения, так что это в общем то бесполезный вариант. Разве что сделать парсер для страницы с диалогами.

С этической точки зрения рекомендую забыть об этом. Такая паранойя ничего хорошего для ваших отношений не принесет. Если вас так напрягает ее скрытность спросите себя нужна ли она вам вообще.

Как говорится решайте вопросы исходя из корня проблемы а не пресекайте симптомы. Тем более, всегда можно завести вторую страницу или общаться через сторонние сервисы.

Answer (score 0):

Можете развернуть обращение к серверу через Jabber протокол [здесь](http://vk.com/help.php?page=jabber)

Через PHP это организовать реально, но наверное понадобится cron, что я думаю не будет помехой